# Windows phone 8 in connected standby mode

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, driver

I have chosen Windows Driver Test Framework (WDTF) for Connected Standby support in windows 8. I am getting below error while compiling.

> Microsoft.WDTF.WDTF2Class' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable
>   interface instead. The type 'Microsoft.WDTF.WDTF2Class' has no
>   constructors defined

All dll references are from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.2\Testing\Development\lib\x86\" . 
Here is the script I have..

```
    IWDTF2 wdtf = new WDTF2Class();
    IWDTFSystemDepot2 systemDepot = wdtf.SystemDepot;
    IWDTFTarget2 systemTarget = systemDepot.ThisSystem;
    IWDTFSystemAction2 systemAction = (IWDTFSystemAction2)systemTarget.GetInterface("System");
    systemAction.ConnectedStandby(1000);
```

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but why do you use the windows-mobile-6 tag? This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025231/force-system-into-connected-standby-state-using-c-windows-api

Comment: Perhaps not stupid either. Removed the Windows-Mobile6 Tag. I am unable to compile the above snippet, even after adding Interop.dll as reference. Any body successfully put the Windows Phone system in to CS mode using WDTF APIs. please respond.

Comment: I found your snippet on a c++ msdn page, what are you trying to do? Give us some more context.

Comment: Context is simple @JPHellemons , Need to put Windows phone in Connected Standby mode using WDTF. Plz provide suggestion if u worked on it.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this exact same issue, and I was finally able to resolve it.  You must include the following two references:

1. WDTF.Interop.dll
2. WDTFSystemAction.Interop.dll

Lack of the second reference will result in the error that you have shared.  Also, the target machine (Windows Surface 3 tablet) required the installation of VC Redistributable (x64), as I was using VS2013, as well as the WDTF Runtimes.  The WDTF runtimes were installed as part of the WDK ([https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh831856(v=vs.85).aspx]).  On my machine, that path was as follows:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Testing\Runtimes\Windows Driver Testing Framework (WDTF) Runtime Libraries-x64_en-us.msi

If you do not install the VC Redistributable, you may receive a "...MSVCR120.DLL is missing from your computer..." message.  Alternatively, if it's compiled as "debug", then the message may reference "MSVCR120D.DLL".

If you do not install the runtimes on the target machine, you will likely receive the following error:

Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the  COM class factory for component with CLSID {0D972387-817B-46E7-913F-E9993FF401E
B} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception f rom HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOn ly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Bo olean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipChec kThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean s kipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)

After completing all of these steps, I was able to make the tablet enter a ConnectedStandby state.  One other thing of note:  when connected through Dameware, the tablet detected input, and refused to enter the ConnectedStandby state.  I was finally able to test by setting this executable to run as scheduled task, and then pinging the tablet to see if/when it lost network connectivity, as well as when it regained network connectivity.

NOTE:  ConnectedStandby_SleepAndWake is my project name in VS2013.

CS, app.config, and project definition (csproj) file are as follows:

***  program.cs ***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.WDTF;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ConnectedStandby_SleepAndWake
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int CSDurationMilliseconds = 0;
            DateTime wakeTime = new DateTime();
            try
            {
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wakeTime"] != null)
            {
                wakeTime = Convert.ToDateTime(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wakeTime"]);
            }
            else
            {
                wakeTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2);
            }

            System.TimeSpan wakeInMs = wakeTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
            CSDurationMilliseconds = wakeInMs.Milliseconds;

            IWDTF2 WDTF = new WDTF2();
            IWDTFSystemAction2 Sys = (IWDTFSystemAction2)WDTF.SystemDepot.ThisSystem.GetInterface("System");
            // Sys.SleepWakeTimeInSeconds = 60;
            // Sys.Sleep(4);

            Sys.ConnectedStandby(CSDurationMilliseconds);
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }



        }
    }
}
```

*** app.config ***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="wakeTime" value="2015-08-16 01:25AM"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

*** ConnectedStandby_SleepAndWake.csproj ***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{657A21BE-8991-4E24-AB41-59D7F0C7D3EB}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>ConnectedStandby_SleepAndWake</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>ConnectedStandby_SleepAndWake</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="WDTF.Interop">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Testing\Development\lib\x64\WDTF.Interop.dll</HintPath>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WDTFInterfaces.Interop">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Testing\Development\lib\x64\WDTFInterfaces.Interop.dll</HintPath>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WDTFSystemAction.Interop">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Testing\Development\lib\x64\WDTFSystemAction.Interop.dll</HintPath>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Client.3.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.  This was an answer to the question.  Did you read the whole response?

Comment: Sorry...Made a mistake